# get userid using vtwsclib

Tags: android, crm, vtiger

I am developing a CRM in Android, and I am using the vtwsclib library in order to make VTiger operations. But the Login function of this library only returns a boolean which says if the user is logged in.

But how could I get the userid? I ask this because I need to do queries which requires it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use $client->doQuery('select * from vtiger_users where user_name='admin'');

That doLogin() function is to get authenticated and get access to perform webservice operations

Comment: Thank you, after doing some tests finally I think that I get how vtiger works